# Radiometric correction of a landsat image using R

Tags: r, landsat

I want to do a radiometric correction of a landsat image using:

```
radiocorr(x, gain, offset, Grescale, Brescale, sunelev, satzenith, edist, Esun, 
    Lhaze, method = "apparentreflectance")
```

I performed the correction to each band, as follow:

```
B1 <- readGDAL("_X20060509_B_1.tif")  
B1.ar<-radiocorr(x = B1, Grescale = 0.76583, Brescale = -2.28583, sunelev = 43.99853366, 
   satzenith = 0, edist = 1.0095786, Esun = 1983, method = "apparentreflectance")
writeGDAL(B1.ar, "C:/Users/Documents/ Reflectance/B1.tif", drivername="GTiff")
```

How can I make one function to automatically perform the correction to the six bands?
I tried with this function:

```
atmcor <- function(img, i) {
  x<-img[[i]]
  Grescale<-gain[i,2]
  Brescale<-bias[i,2]
  sunelev<-sunelevation[i,2]
  satzenith=0
  edist<-edistance[i,2]
  Esun<-Esun[1,2]
  method = "apparentreflectance"
  B.ar<-radiocorr(x, Grescale, Brescale, sunelev, satzenith, edist, Esun, method)
  return(B.ar)
}

ATMCOR <- atmcor(landsat_stack, 1)
```

But, I got this error:
(Error in array(x, c(length(x), 1L), if (!is.null(names(x))) list(names(x),  : 
  length of 'dimnames' [1] not equal to array extent)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do the radiometric calibration for all bands in only one execution chunk you need to load your metadata file as well. 
Therefore you can do it in several forms. But the following code can easily solve your problem.

```
 radCor(img, metaData, method = "apref", bandSet = "full", hazeValues,
 hazeBands, atmosphere, darkProp = 0.01, clamp = TRUE, verbose)
```

When you set the bandSet to "full", all the band in the solar region will be processed.